# stm32cube ide, build error saying Cannot find the specified linker script

Tags: linker, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubeide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo2XQ.png)
I'm using stm32cube ide, but after configuring the chip in CubeMX, when I build the project, I get this error:

Error: Cannot find the specified linker script. Check the linker settings in the build configuration.
make: *** [makefile:93: fail-specified-linker-script-missing] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs...

May i have a suggestion ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTAPl.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot that shows "Problems" tab. So we can see detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when cloning a new repo to my local system. STM32CubeIDE seems to not index the .ld files into the project, even when they are in the folder. I just started a new project from existing .ioc file. Then i selected the file that was in the project I wanted to use, and ported all the code from that project to the new one. A work around but at least it gets you up and running

Answer (score 0):

No need to redo the project, just move your linker script(your PackageName_FLASH.ld file) into the right place, right-click on the project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MCU G++ Linker -> General -> Linker Script text box,and adjust the path and name of the linker script to match your case.